# How to remove messages based on age or message count in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, mail-rule

Is there any way to delete emails in a folder after there are a certain number of emails in the folder? Or would it be easier just to set up a rule to delete all emails in the folder at the end of a day? Would I do this in MS Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft Outlook you can use Auto Archive to achieve this. You can set it to delete items older than a certain number of days(or move them, or whatever).

First create a rule to move certain emails to a folder.Then right click the folder and choose properties. Choose the Autoarchive tab, then choose to archive using these settings, and permanently delete old items. This will get rid of them after the specified number of days.